# 403 forbidden mongoDB driver for golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm importing `mongo-driver` in the project. but when I run

```
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

I get `403 Forbidden` and the error message looks like this:

```
go: downloading github.com/klauspost/compress v1.13.6

go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo imports
        go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver imports
        github.com/klauspost/compress/zstd: github.com/klauspost/compress@v1.13.6: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/klauspost/compress/@v/v1.13.6.zip: 403 Forbidden
```

What should I do?

Comment: That is strange ... When I point my browser to [`https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/klauspost/compress/@v/v1.13.6.zip`](https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/klauspost/compress/@v/v1.13.6.zip), it downloads without error.  I also wonder why `mongo-driver` is using `compress@v1.13.6` (more than a year old) when `compress@v1.15.12` is available.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Correct, when I open the website it shows`Access Denied, Not Available in your location`

Answer (score 0):

Some Google services are blocked in some countries. If that's your case, you need to use a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to change your IP address.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already using VPN to visit Stackoverflow . Do we have another solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).